# Cannot update mongodb record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When I try to execute the following command:

```
db.users.update(
   { _id: 5392beaf0e50cfe50a781e19 }, 
   { $set: { 'role': 'admin' }
})
```

I got the following errors:

```
Sat Jun  7 16:24:58.798 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast an ObjectId and your JSON syntax is also illegal:

```js
db.users.update(
   { _id: ObjectId("5392beaf0e50cfe50a781e19") }, 
   { $set: { 'role': 'admin' }
})
```